# Why doesn't my custom mouse cursor load after restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, cursor

I have created a new personal preferences profile in Windows 7 which cycles my background pictures from a custom folder location and changed my mouse cursor.  When I save this profile and activate it, everything runs as it should.  My problem is when I restart my computer, my mouse cursor is back to the default but my custom background setting is still active.  I have to reopen my preferences and click on my profile to activate it.  Why doesn't my OS load my cursor automatically ?

Things to note:

- I am using a logitech G500.
- OS: Windows 7 (happened within multiple OS builds)
- I have tried:

  - Deleting & reinstalling mouse driver
  - Creating new profiles
  - multiple mouses
  - different cursors
  - removed logitech services from the start up

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that custom profiles are set as 'Themes' and the referenced cursors only happen at save or reload.

To fix this:  make a copy of the referenced cursors and paste them into the C:\Windows\Cursor folder to be called upon start up.  Then re-find the cursors stored in that windows cursor location (default location themes look at - regardless if you change them manually)

Comment: I just saved my unsaved theme and set the cursor back to what I wanted. Now it works without any problem. Thanks for the suggestion, it fixed my problem too.

Comment: It's ridiculous that this bug hasn't been fixed in all those years...

Answer (score 2):

The solution of copying custom cursors inside Windows\Cursor folder works. But I found that it also works if you copy them to other system folders outside Windows, like ProgramData. Finally, I found that the background problem is another.

Windows stores cursor configuration in Registry under key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors
```

If your custom cursor file is located inside any folder under your profile, Windows rewrites its path using *%UserProfile%* variable. It seems that this is the offending part. If you go to that registry key and manually rewrite those full paths without using *%UserProfile%* variable, custom cursors will load normally at startup, wherever the files are located.

It’s still a bug, but at least it’s a cleaner workaround than copying files into Windows folders.

Comment: A good recent answer. This may be true. I never had a problem when my cursors were in a second separate, non-OS holding internal hard disk. But within my user folder, it keep resetting upon restart.

Comment: This was exactly what was blocking me from using a high-visibility cursor (that I had designed for myself wayyyyyy back when I was a poor student with a very dim and low-contrast passive matrix laptop screen.)

Answer (score -2):

I researched a lot and found this:

1. Copy this into file explorer: `C:\Windows\Cursor`
2. Drag your own cursor into the folder, and it should stay after restart.